# Java: How to scale 2D graphics with LWJGL to fit different resolutions

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl, scaling

I'm currently in the process of learning the LWJGL (2.9.3) library for a game engine I'm making. Everything in the engine is running fine so far, except for one thing: different resolutions. I started a separate project to keep things clean just to see if it was something obvious that I missed, but that didn't help.

My code basically just draws a red block near the upper left corner so I could make sure the scaling actually worked. Currently, if the resolution is changed to a resolution greater than the monitor it works fine. But if the resolution is changed to a resolution greater than that of the monitor, the block changes size and moves. I've tried making variables that change the scaling relative to the resolutions, I've tried playing with *glOrtho*, and I've tried playing with *glMatrixMode*. Nothing seems to be working. I'll put my code below and see if one of you lovely people can figure out what's going on.

The main class:

```
    import static helperPackage.Artist.*;

    public class Test {

        // Everything will be rendered to a 1920 x 1080 display
        public final int windowWidth = 1920;
        public final int windowHeight = 1080;
        // These are the current widths and heights that are changed
        public static int cWindowWidth = 1920;
        public static int cWindowHeight = 1080;
        // Everything is full screen and VSync enabled
        public boolean isFullscreen = true;
        public boolean enableVSync = true;
        // Scale variables (I tried using these and they only made it worse)
        public float scaleX;
        public float scaleY;

        public Test()
        {
            setScales();

            beginSession(windowWidth, windowHeight, isFullscreen, enableVSync);

            while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
            {
                /*
                 * Code to draw a poorly made house
                DrawQuad( 200 * scaleX, 200 * scaleY, 300 * scaleX, 200 * scaleY, 255, 0, 0);
                DrawQuad( 325 * scaleX, 310 * scaleY, 50 * scaleX, 90 * scaleY, 115, 60, 0);
                DrawQuad( 240 * scaleX, 310 * scaleY, 50 * scaleX, 40 * scaleY, 175, 220, 255);
                DrawQuad( 410 * scaleX, 310 * scaleY, 50 * scaleX, 40 * scaleY, 175, 220, 255);
                DrawQuad( 240 * scaleX, 225 * scaleY, 50 * scaleX, 40 * scaleY, 175, 220, 255);
                DrawQuad( 410 * scaleX, 225 * scaleY, 50 * scaleX, 40 * scaleY, 175, 220, 255);
                DrawQuad( 325 * scaleX, 225 * scaleY, 50 * scaleX, 40 * scaleY, 175, 220, 255);
                DrawTriangle(100 * scaleX, 200 * scaleY, 600 * scaleX, 200 * scaleY, 350 * scaleX, 100 * scaleY, 115, 60, 0);
                */

                // The quad used for testing
                DrawQuad( 200, 200, 300, 200, 255, 0, 0);

                // The code to change resolutions while the application is running
                 while (Keyboard.next()) 
                 {
                        if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) 
                        {
                            if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_1) 
                            {
                                cWindowWidth = 1920;
                                cWindowHeight = 1080;
                                setScales();
                                updateDisplayMode(cWindowWidth, cWindowHeight, true);
                            }
                            else if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_2) 
                            {
                                cWindowWidth = 800;
                                cWindowHeight = 600;
                                setScales();
                                updateDisplayMode(cWindowWidth, cWindowHeight, true);
                            }
                            else if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_3) 
                            {
                                cWindowWidth = 640;
                                cWindowHeight = 480;
                                setScales();
                                updateDisplayMode(cWindowWidth, cWindowHeight, true);
                            }
                            else if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_4) 
                            {
                                cWindowWidth = 4800;
                                cWindowHeight = 2700;
                                setScales();
                                updateDisplayMode(cWindowWidth, cWindowHeight, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                Display.update();
                Display.sync(60);
            }

            Display.destroy();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new Test();
        }

        // Sets the scale variables
        private void setScales()
        {
            scaleX = cWindowWidth / windowWidth; 
            scaleY = cWindowHeight / windowHeight;
        }

    }
```

And the Artist class:

```
        package helperPackage;

        public class Artist {

            public static void beginSession(int windowW, int windowH, boolean isFS, boolean isVS)
            {
                // Sets the Title of the application
                Display.setTitle("LWJGL Tests");
                try
                {
                    // Sets the default resolution and full screen
                    updateDisplayMode(windowW, windowH, isFS);
                    // Enables VSync
                    Display.setVSyncEnabled(isVS);

                    // Sets the icons in the window and the task bar
                    Display.setIcon(new ByteBuffer[] 
                            {
                                    new ImageIOImageData().imageToByteBuffer(ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/LOGOx32.png")), false, false, null),
                                    new ImageIOImageData().imageToByteBuffer(ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/LOGOx16.png")), false, false, null)   
                            }
                    );

                    // Creates the display with Anti Aliasing
                    Display.create(new PixelFormat(0, 24, 8, 4));
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                glLoadIdentity();
                glOrtho(0.0D, 1920.0D, 1080.0D, 0.0D, 1.0D, -1.0D);
                glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            }

            public static void updateDisplayMode(int width, int height, boolean fullscreen)
            {

                // Exits method if current DisplayMode is the target DisplayMode
                 if ((Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth() == width) && (Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight() == height) && (Display.isFullscreen() == fullscreen)) 
                 {
                            return;
                 }

                 // Try/Catch to handle errors
                 try 
                 {

                     // Initializes the target DisplayMode
                        DisplayMode targetDisplayMode = null;

                        // Lowers the target dimensions to dimensions within range to prevent crashing
                        if (width > Display.getDesktopDisplayMode().getWidth())
                        {
                             width = Display.getDesktopDisplayMode().getWidth();    
                        }
                        if (height > Display.getDesktopDisplayMode().getHeight())
                        {
                             height = Display.getDesktopDisplayMode().getHeight();
                        }

                        // Adjusts frequency and bits per pixel if the target is to be full screen
                        if (fullscreen)
                        {

                            // Initializes an array of compatible DisplayModes
                            DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();

                            // Initializes a variable for the refresh rate of the monitor
                            int freq = 0;

                            // Creates a variable for temporary use in the loop
                            DisplayMode current;

                            // Sorts through all compatible DisplayModes
                            for (int i=0; i < modes.length; i++) 
                            {

                                // Sets current to the DisplayMode being tested in the loop
                                current = modes[i];

                                // Checks to see if the temporary DisplayMode has the same dimensions as the target DisplayMode
                                if ((current.getWidth() == width) && (current.getHeight() == height)) 
                                {
                                    // Tries to find a compatible refresh rate
                                    if ((targetDisplayMode == null) || (current.getFrequency() >= freq))
                                    {
                                        // Tries to find a compatible bits per pixel
                                        if ((targetDisplayMode == null) || (current.getBitsPerPixel() > targetDisplayMode.getBitsPerPixel()))
                                        {
                                            targetDisplayMode = current;
                                            freq = targetDisplayMode.getFrequency();
                                        }
                                    }

                                   // If bits per pixel and frequency match the display values
                                   // it breaks the loop to set the DisplayMode
                                    if ((current.getBitsPerPixel() == Display.getDesktopDisplayMode().getBitsPerPixel()) && (current.getFrequency() == Display.getDesktopDisplayMode().getFrequency()))
                                    {
                                        targetDisplayMode = current;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                        // If the target is not full screen
                        else 
                        {
                            targetDisplayMode = new DisplayMode(width, height);
                        }

                        // Prevents switching to an unsupported DisplayMode
                        if (targetDisplayMode == null) {
                            System.out.println("Failed to find value mode: " + width + "x" + height + " fs=" + fullscreen);
                            return;
                        }

                        // Sets the DisplayMode
                        Display.setDisplayMode(targetDisplayMode);
                        Display.setFullscreen(fullscreen);

                 } 
                 // Catches any exceptions
                 catch (LWJGLException e) 
                 {
                        System.out.println("Unable to setup mode " + width + "x" + height + " fullscreen=" + fullscreen + e);
                 }
            }

            public static void DrawQuad(float x, float y, float width, float height, float red, float green, float blue)
            {
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glColor3f(red / 255, green / 255, blue / 255);
                glVertex2f(x, y);
                glVertex2f(x + width, y);
                glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
                glVertex2f(x, y + height);
                glEnd();
            }

        }
```

Note: The actual code has all proper imports

Comment: You may want to consider LibGDX before making your own engine.

Comment: I have looked into it, however this is also for a school project so I do actually need to make an engine

Comment: You really shouldn't be using LWJGL 2.x. The only reason that version is being maintained is to keep "production" code working for projects that were started with LWJGL 2.x. You should be using LWJGL 3.x for any projects you start.

Comment: Thank you for your advice on which version of lwjgl to use. I'll try to switch over